# Какой стек технологий необходим для того, чтобы устроится на работу Android разработчиком?

Tags: java, android

Пишу приложения под Android на java. На данный момент написал несколько не очень сложных приложений. 
Но проблема в том, что я не знаю, какие технологии мне нужно изучать для того, чтобы меня взяли на работу по этой специальности
В интернете информации по этому поводу достаточно мало
Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: к любой вакансии идет список требований и пожеланий

Comment: Стоит начать ходить на собеседования и сразу поймешь чего тебе не хватает... Я перед тем как найти первую работу прошел порядка 25 собесов, начал ходить очень рано и учился в основном на собесах и тестовых заданиях. И потом этот навык очень пригодился при поиске второй работы, т.к. смог совершить очень крутой скачек в крутую компанию благодаря тому что был очень большой опыт собесов и умение уверенно на них держаться. А еще когда на собесе во что-то натыкают носом, это намного лучше запомнинается=). Так что собесы, собесы и еще раз собесы и не бояться=)

Comment: @СергейБувака, спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В интернете информации по этому поводу предостаточно.
Просто ищите вакансии по андроиду и смотрите требования.

Сами требования зависят от компании.
В некоторых случаях достаточно пары пунктов, а в некоторых список будет из десятков пунктов.

Вот для примера несколько пунктов:

- Знание Java и Kotlin
- Знание классических алгоритмов и структур данных
- Знание принципов ООП и шаблонов проектирования
- Знание: TDD, MVVM, MVP, SOLID, CI, DI, Clean Architecture
- Навыки многопоточной разработки
- Навыки профилирования
- Опыт работы Android разработчиком от 1 года
- Опыт разработки нативных Android-приложений
- Опыт работы с GooglePlay Services, Architecture Components, Jetpack, Coroutines

и т.п.

Ещё, почти везде нужно:

- Наличие законченных проектов в портфолио